# lvmetad is not up in systemd even though enabled in lvm.conf file(use_lvmetad=1). lvmetad is not coming up by default

Tags: linux, systemd, lvm, distro

Trying to bring up system with systemd.
If I start lvm2 manually it comes up, but not coming up by default at booting time. 
If not enabled manually getting warning   "/var/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try *systemctl enable lvmetad.service*?

Comment: if i start manually with this command.

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae : lvmetad works with command execution. I wanted to bring up with boot. Is there any way to debug it.

Comment: I found further "lvm2-lvmetad.service" is dependent on "lvm2-lvmetad.socket". This socket creates one ListenStream which is not being creating at boot time. can someone explain how this listen stream gets created ?